# Relay switch problem: Arduino Nano with a 312 PIR sensor

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano, relay

I am working with a 312 PIR sensor with an Arduino Uno Nano.

When sensing motion Port 13 goes High for Time_A (10 minutes). If I then press a push button on the Arduino board it takes Port D2 LOW, then Port A will be on for Time 2 (A quick 30 second test cycle for testing and/or troubleshooting the code and equipment and a second LED (Port 12 goes high).

So, the sensor turns on the light relay for 10 minutes and the push button makes the light and the LED stay on for only 30 seconds so I can quickly test the system.
I have all the above working perfectly, but I have having difficulty adding another section of code that will turn all of the above off after either the 10 minutes, or the 30 second cycle. Now the lights stay on until I reset and start the cycle over for one of the times determined by the button, or the sensor.

Below is the code :

```cpp
//Serial.println("TOP OF PROGRAM");
float pressLength_milliSeconds = 0; // value will be recorded in seconds. Define minimum time, in milli-seconds 
int optionOne_milliSeconds = 100;
int optionTwo_milliSeconds = 2000;  // the pin your button is attached to
int buttonPin = 2; // pin your LEDs are attached to
int ledPin_Option_1 = 13;
int ledPin_Option_2 = 12;

void setup() {   // initialize pushbutton input pullup. Keep in mind, pin2 has ground voltage applied, we
  Serial.println("Top of SKETCH");
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP); // set the LEDS pins as outputs
  pinMode(ledPin_Option_1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin_Option_2, OUTPUT); // start serial communications - for debutting   purposes or 
  Serial.begin(9600);
} // close set up

void loop() { // record roughly the of tenths of seconds the button is being pressed
  while (digitalRead(buttonPin) == LOW ) {
    delay(5); // if you want more resolution, lower this number
    pressLength_milliSeconds = pressLength_milliSeconds + 100;   //display how long button is has been held
    Serial.print("ms =  ");
    Serial.println("pressLength_milliSeconds");
  } // close while     //Option 2 - Execute the second option if the button is held for the correct amount of time
  if (pressLength_milliSeconds >= optionTwo_milliSeconds) {
    digitalWrite(ledPin_Option_2, HIGH);
  }  // option 1 - Execute the first option if the  button is held long enough
  else if (pressLength_milliSeconds >= optionOne_milliSeconds) {
    digitalWrite(ledPin_Option_1, HIGH);
  } // close if options. every loop - reset  pressLength_Seconds counter
  //if (optionTwo_milliSeconds >= 10000)
  //  delay(10000);
  //digitalWrite(ledPin_Option_1, LOW);
  //digitalWrite(ledPin_Option_2, LOW);
  pressLength_milliSeconds = 0;
}
```

Comment: use button to control the timer, not LED ... use timer to control the LED ... you could separate the control even more by using timer to control a flag, then use the flag to control the LED

Comment: So there's two conditions that are supposed to make the light turn on? Within 10 minutes after a sensor signal on pin XX or within 30 seconds after a button press on pin 2?  I'd record the `micros()` when the button was pressed, and the `micros()` when the sensor was pressed and do the logic for the LED.